# Use ApplicationContext in Helper-Class

Tags: java, android, authentication, nullpointerexception, android-context

**What I'm trying to do**

---

I'm trying to create a Login which is fully handled in a `Helperclass`, to keep the code simple.

For this I created a `helperclass` with all the functionality I need, now the Problem is that I always get a `NullPointer-Exception`, probably because of the `getApplicationContext`.

**Question**

---

So what do I need to change in my Code to get this working. The code is provided below. If you have a great tutorial or something please provide me this. I really like to do this on my own.

**Code**

---

LoginActivity.class

```
package de.ivocore;


public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    private DBAdapter mDbHelper;

    private LoginHelper login = new LoginHelper();



    **/
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        mDbHelper = new DBAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.open();
        mDbHelper.close();

        // Text-Felder
        final EditText user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_username);
        final EditText pwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_password);

        // Button
        Button loginbt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_login);

        // OnClickListner für den Button definieren
        loginbt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Eingegebener Username und Passwort auslesen
                final String usertxt = user.getText().toString();
                final String pwdtxt = pwd.getText().toString();
                Log.d("User", usertxt);
                Log.d("PWD", pwdtxt);

                checkLoginData(usertxt, pwdtxt);
            }
        });

    }   

public void checkLoginData(final String username, final String password){

    boolean user, pass;

    if (username.length() < 6){
        user = false;
    }else {
        user = true;
    }

    if (password.length() < 6){
        pass = false;
    }else {
        pass = true;
    }

    int val = 0;
    if (user) val |= 0x1;
    if (pass) val |= 0x2;

    switch (val){
    case 0:
        login.loginFalse(getApplicationContext(),"Username und Passwort müssen mindestens 6 Zeichen haben");

    break;

    case 1:
        login.loginFalse(getApplicationContext(),"Passwort muss mindestens 6 Zeichen haben");
    break;

    case 2:
        login.loginFalse(getApplicationContext(),"Username muss mindestens 6 Zeichen haben");
    break;

    case 3:
        login.doLogin(getApplicationContext(),username, password);
    }

}
}
```

LoginHelper.class

```
package de.ivocore.firstboot;


public class LoginHelper {

    private static final String PREFS_NAME = "de.ivocore.firstboot.PREF_NAME";
    private static final String PREFS_USER = "de.ivocore.firstboot.PREF_USER";
    private static final String PREF_FIRSTBOOT = "de.ivocore.firstboot.FIRSTBOOT";

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private static SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    boolean first;
    Context test;

    // Handlet die Message aus dem Thread
    private Handler handler = new Handler() {

        public void handleLogin(Message msg) {

            switch(msg.what){
            case 0: {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Intent i = new Intent(test, MainActivity.class);
                test.startActivity(i);

            } break;

            case 1:{
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                String text = "Username oder Passwort inkorrekt";
                loginFalse(test, text);
            } break;
        }

        }
    };

    /**
     * Hier wird ein AlertDialog erzeugt welcher zurück gibt ob was am Login
     * falsch war.
     * 
     * @param ctx
     *            Context der Klasse
     * @param text
     *            Text der ausgegeben werden soll
     */
    public void loginFalse(Context ctx, String text) {

        AlertDialog alertDialog;
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx)
                .setMessage(text)
                .setTitle("Login inkorrekt")
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.cancel,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {
                            }
                        }).show();
    }

    public void doLogin(final Context ctx, final String username,
            final String password) {

        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ctx, "Login", "Bitte warten...");

        Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                String URL = "http://LOGINURL (NotForYourEyes)"

                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response;


                try {
                    //Firstboot überprüfung

                    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);
                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity("username=" + username
                            + "&password=" + password);
                    post.setEntity(se);
                    post.addHeader("Content-Type",
                            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); // Dieser
                                                                    // Header is
                                                                    // von curl
                                                                    // -d Befehl
                                                                    // abgeleitet
                    response = client.execute(post);

                    int statuscode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                    switch (statuscode) {

                    case 200:

                        if (response != null) {

                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                                    new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity()
                                            .getContent()));

                            String line;
                            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                                sb.append(line + "\n");
                            }

                            String result;
                            result = sb.toString();

                            // User-Id auslesen
                            final String uid;
                            JSONObject holder = new JSONObject(result);
                            uid = holder.getString("id");
                            Log.d("JSON-Response", uid);

                            String token = "test-token";


                             SharedPreferences logindata = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_USER, 0);
                             SharedPreferences.Editor editor = logindata.edit(); editor.clear();
                             editor.putString("userid", uid);
                             editor.putString("token", token);
                             editor.commit();


                            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                        }
                        break;

                    case 500:

                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);

                        break;

                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("DataHandler", "URLConnection-Error" + e);
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }

    /**
     * Mit dieser Methode wird heraussgesucht ob der erste Login bereits
     * geschehen ist
     * 
     * @return firstboot
     */
    private boolean getFirstboot() {
        boolean firstboot = mPrefs.getBoolean(PREF_FIRSTBOOT, first);
        return firstboot;
    }

    /**
     * Hier wird die Variabel auf true gesetzt, falls der Firstboot bereits
     * passiert ist.
     * 
     * @param first
     */
    private static void setFirstboot(boolean first) {
        mPrefs.edit().putBoolean(PREF_FIRSTBOOT, first).commit();
    }

}
```

---

LogCat:

```
   03-14 08:12:53.464: E/AndroidRuntime(9462): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
03-14 08:12:53.464: E/AndroidRuntime(9462):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:519)
03-14 08:12:53.464: E/AndroidRuntime(9462):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:279)
03-14 08:12:53.464: E/AndroidRuntime(9462):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:193)
03-14 08:12:53.464: E/AndroidRuntime(9462):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:118)
03-14 08:12:53.464: E/AndroidRuntime(9462):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:274)
03-14 08:12:53.464: E/AndroidRuntime(9462):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:932)
03-14 08:12:53.464: E/AndroidRuntime(9462):     at de.ivocore.firstboot.LoginHelper.loginFalse(LoginHelper.java:80)
03-14 08:12:53.464: E/AndroidRuntime(9462):     at de.ivocore.LoginActivity.checkLoginData(LoginActivity.java:120)
03-14 08:12:53.464: E/AndroidRuntime(9462):     at de.ivocore.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:92)
03-14 08:12:53.464: E/AndroidRuntime(9462):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
03-14 08:12:53.464: E/AndroidRuntime(9462):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
03-14 08:12:53.464: E/AndroidRuntime(9462):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
03-14 08:12:53.464: E/AndroidRuntime(9462):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-14 08:12:53.464: E/AndroidRuntime(9462):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-14 08:12:53.464: E/AndroidRuntime(9462):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
03-14 08:12:53.464: E/AndroidRuntime(9462):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-14 08:12:53.464: E/AndroidRuntime(9462):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-14 08:12:53.464: E/AndroidRuntime(9462):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-14 08:12:53.464: E/AndroidRuntime(9462):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-14 08:12:53.464: E/AndroidRuntime(9462):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

If you need more code, or more detailed information just write it in the comments below.

Comment: can you post logcat of your NPE? What if you use just `this` as Context?

Comment: where do you define loginHelper? Looks like nowhere...

Comment: i did private LoginHelper login;

Comment: Yes you did private LoginHelper login; but where is login = new LoginHelper(); or something? Your login is null.

Comment: @safari if you do initialize login variable with something, then please add a trailing comment on the line 120 in the LoginActivity class, because this is where the exception happens: de.ivocore.LoginActivity.checkLoginData(LoginActivity.java:120)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getApplicationContext();
```

For dialogs or any other UI altering functions you have to pass this from your activity.

getApplicationContext() should be used only when the UI is not involved (loading resources, prefs, .. etc).

Comment: allright, what can I do than to get the context? and give it to my helperclass?

Comment: Instead of calling login.loginFalse(getApplicationContext() , ...)

just call login.loginFalse(this, ...)

Activity implements Context

Comment: tell me, the one who's the prittier one.

Comment: Instead of calling login.loginFalse(getApplicationContext() , ...) just call login.loginFalse(this, ...) Activity implements Context

Comment: and do this for all methods that display dialogs or do any UI in your helper

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(getParent()).inflate(
            R.layout.login, null);
    setContentView(view);
```

I fixed my own problem with this

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing LoginHelper.  In the current code, it will be null.

Comment: ok, did this, now I get a new exception '03-14 08:12:53.464: E/AndroidRuntime(9462): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application'